# Proving there is no isomorphism between $S_\infty$ and $A_\infty$

Tags: group-theory

My teacher said this is the case because $A_\infty$ is generated by elements of order $3$ (the 3-cycles), and $S_\infty$ is not. I understand that the 3-cycles do not generate $S_n$, and that $\phi(x) = y \implies \text{order}(x) = \text{order}(y)$, but why can't there be an isomorphism between another set of generators of $A_\infty$ (say the two cycles), and a set of generators of $S_\infty$?

Comment: A generating set for the symmetric group must contain at least one odd permutation, but the alternating group has no odd permutations.

Comment: @Joppy, but the alternating group does have elements like $(12)(34)$ of the same order as the odd permutation $(12)$.

Comment: $A_{\infty}$ is simple, but not $S_{\infty}$, it is true that this does not really answer your question, but is an argument which shows both groups are not isomorphic.

Comment: What is $S_\infty$? My first guess would be the permutations of $\mathbb N$, but then I don't see how we'd define even and odd. Maybe the permutations that fix all but finitely many elements? That would be the same as the products of finitely many (finite) cycles...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich it's defined as $\cup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}S_k$, and $A_\infty$ the same way, but then with $A_k$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose that $\phi:A_\infty \to S_\infty$ is an isomorphism. We know that $A_\infty = \langle X \rangle$, where $X$ is the set of $3$-cycles. It follows that $S_\infty = \phi(\langle X \rangle) = \langle \{\phi(x) : x \in X \} \rangle$.

Since $\phi(x)$ has order $3$ for all $x \in X$, it follows that $S_\infty$ is generated by a set of elements of order $3$. But every such element in $S_\infty$ is an even permutation, so this is a contradiction. Hence there can be no such isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Every element in $A_{\infty}$ is a product of an even number of transpositions. If $\tau_1$, $\tau_2$, $\tau$  are transpositions, we have 
$\tau_1 \tau_2 = (\tau_1 \tau)( \tau \tau_2)$. Hence every element in $A_{\infty}$ can be written as a product of an even number of elements of the form $\eta_1 \eta_2$, where $\eta_1$, $\eta_2$ are transpositions with disjoint support. Note also that all such elements are conjugate in $A_{\infty}$ to $(1,2)(3,4)$.
Let $f\colon A_{\infty}\to S_{\infty}$ be a morphism of groups. Every element in $f(A_{\infty})$ is a product of an even number of conjugates of $f((1,2)(3,4))$, so of signature $+1$. Hence $\phi(A_{\infty})\subset A_{\infty}$.

Comment: $f((1,2))$ does not make sense because $(1,2) \not\in A_\infty$.

Comment: @Derek Holt: Thanks for pointing that out!  Remade the proof.

Comment: Yes it works now, but you haven't said what $\tau$ is.